# Передача сообщений Android приложению из Lite Wearable Harmony OS

Tags: huawei

У меня есть некоторое приложение Harmony OS под Lite Wearable устройство, которое должно передавать некоторое сообщение Android приложению, приемлемо даже без ответа. Порывшись, я понял как отправлять запросы приложению, а именно через WearSDK, но не до конца понял как именно их принимать и какой фреймворк и язык лучше подойдёт для такого приложения (функций вне приёма этих сообщений нету)